# Notification for MPMoviePlayerViewController when the entire file is not available?

Tags: iphone, video

All,

This is regarding Question on iPhone , playing video

My app is downloading a youtube file and at the same time, i want to play the video from the local.

Am able to do this using MPMoviePlayerViewController, but i donot receive any notifications if the player has stopped playing half-way as the entire file content was not available.

e.g. say a 10MB content of 5 minutes video is currently downloading and the downloading is stopped, the App has just downloaded 5 MB or 2.5 minutes of the video, when i play the video, i am be able to view the video until 2.5 minutes but i donot receive any notification after the video has stopped playing.

Is there a notification that tells "video content not available" "end of movie"

--Srihari

Answer (score 10):

Per [`MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMoviePlayerController)

### MPMovieFinishReason

```
enum {
  MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded,
  MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError,
  MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited
};
typedef NSInteger MPMovieFinishReason;
```

### Notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(playbackFinished:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

### Example

```
- (void)playbackFinished:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
    NSNumber * reason = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];
    switch ([reason intValue]) {
        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded:
            NSLog(@"Playback Ended");         
            break;
        case MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackError:
            NSLog(@"Playback Error");
            break;
        case MPMovieFinishReasonUserExited:
            NSLog(@"User Exited");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. i have already registered for the notification, but i donot receive the notification.

Comment: The following the problem: currently my app downloads a video content and the user is allowed to play the content from the local cache. But if the video content is not downloaded completely, the user can still play the content until the downloaded portion and the rest of the part the video needs to be streamed.

Comment: You can always do a file size comparison of the local and remote files. And if the sizes do not match, do not even allow the video to play, or display an alert to retry the download.